# jQuery.each iterating over list twice when there are three objects in it. Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, visualforce, apex

There are three objects inside plan_unit_list_items, but only two li are appended to my ul. Can anyone tell me why this might be?

```
var plan_unit_list_items = {!planUnitList}; // APEX METHOD
var openPlanUnitList = function (unitdiv) {
    jQuery('div.plan_unit_dropdown').remove();
    var plan_unit_dr = jQuery('<div>')
        .addClass('plan_unit_dropdown')
        .append('<ul>');
    jQuery.each(plan_unit_list_items,

    function (idx, val) {
        jQuery('.plan_unit_dropdown ul').append(
        jQuery('<li>')
            .addClass('plan_unit_list_items')
            .text(val.Name))
        plan_unit_dr.appendTo(unitdiv);
    })
}
```

(And I apologise if 'iterating' is the wrong terminology in the question)

Comment: Got any more code? Where's the object/array list?

Comment: `var plan_unit_list_items = {!planUnitList}; ` If that variable is `planUnitList` is defined, you understand that `plan_unit_list_items` will be false, right?

Comment: So it isn't iterating over the list twice, it's iterating through two items in the list when there are three?

Comment: @RPM: That's a syntax error and looks more like some serverside processing-language template syntax.

Comment: Why are you calling `plan_unit_dr.appendTo(unitdiv);` on every iteration?

Comment: @JLRishe, you're right. That should be outside the jQuery.each right?

Comment: Yes, I would think so.

Comment: When you say it's only iterating over two items, is it the first two or the last two items?

Comment: The first two items. So the final is being ignored somehow?

Comment: Open your developer tools and inspect the contents of the `ul`. It may contain an empty `li`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your code, it looks like you are creating a `ul` and then trying to append `li`s to it, but you are using the following selector to select the `ul` from the DOM when it hasn't yet been added to the DOM until after the first iteration:

```
jQuery('.plan_unit_dropdown ul')
```

So on the first iteration, no appending happens. Since you already have access to the newly-created `ul`, why not just append directly to that rather than re-selecting it?

```
var openPlanUnitList = function (unitdiv) {
    jQuery('div.plan_unit_dropdown').remove();
    var plan_unit_ul = jQuery('<ul>'),
        plan_unit_dr = jQuery('<div>')
            .addClass('plan_unit_dropdown')
            .append(plan_unit_ul);

    plan_unit_dr.appendTo(unitdiv);

    jQuery.each(plan_unit_list_items, function (idx, val) {
        plan_unit_ul.append(jQuery('<li>')
                              .addClass('plan_unit_list_items')
                              .text(val.Name));
    });
};
```